# PYGAME: sysFont ERROR

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, sys

i am following allong with a pygame-tutorial but i have, even if i use the source code, this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michaël\Documents\pythonfile\Text-5.py", line 29, in <module>
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
  File "C:\Users\Michaël\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sysfont.py", line 320, in SysFont
    return constructor(fontname, size, set_bold, set_italic)
  File "C:\Users\Michaël\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sysfont.py", line 243, in font_constructor
    font = pygame.font.Font(fontpath, size)
OSError: unable to read font file 'C:\Users\Michaël\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
 packages\pygame\freesansbold.ttf'
```

i tried to use pygame.font.Font insted of pygame.font.SysFont but that doesn't seem to solve my problem. furthermore i tried font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 25) but that still resulted in an error. Thanks for the help :)

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')

gameExit = False

lead_x = display_width/2
lead_y = display_height/2
lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

block_size = 10
FPS = 60
pygame.font.init()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)


def message_to_screen(msg,color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text,[display_width/2,display_height/2])

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -(block_size/2)
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = block_size/2
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change = -(block_size/2)
                lead_x_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change = block_size/2
                lead_x_change = 0
    if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x <= 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y <= 0:
        gameExit = True

    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x,lead_y,block_size, block_size])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(FPS)

message_to_screen("GAME OVER",red)
pygame.display.update()

time.sleep(2)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: have you checked the contents of the pygame directory?

Comment: i mannaged to resolve it, it only word with pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 25)  so i al not copletly sure if its good enough, but for now i am fine :) i indeed had a directory issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the instruction `pygame.font.get_fonts()` to search the available sysfonts.

```
import pygame
pygame.font.get_fonts()
['arial', 'arialblack', 'bahnschrift', 'calibri', 'cambriacambriamath', 'cambria', 'candara', 'comicsansms', 'consolas', 'constantia', 'corbel', 'couriernew', 'ebrima', 'franklingothicmedium', 'gabriola', 'gadugi', 'georgia', 'impact', 'inkfree', 'javanesetext', 'leelawadeeui', 'leelawadeeuisemilight', 'lucidaconsole', 'lucidasans', 'malgungothic', 'malgungothicsemilight', 'microsofthimalaya', 'microsoftjhengheimicrosoftjhengheiui', 'microsoftjhengheimicrosoftjhengheiuibold', 'microsoftjhengheimicrosoftjhengheiuilight', 'microsoftnewtailue', 'microsoftphagspa', 'microsoftsansserif', 'microsofttaile', 'microsoftyaheimicrosoftyaheiui', 'microsoftyaheimicrosoftyaheiuibold', 'microsoftyaheimicrosoftyaheiuilight', 'microsoftyibaiti', 'mingliuextbpmingliuextbmingliuhkscsextb', 'mongolianbaiti', 'msgothicmsuigothicmspgothic', 'mvboli', 'myanmartext', 'nirmalaui', 'nirmalauisemilight', 'palatinolinotype', 'segoemdl2assets', 'segoeprint', 'segoescript', 'segoeui', 'segoeuiblack', 'segoeuiemoji', 'segoeuihistoric', 'segoeuisemibold', 'segoeuisemilight', 'segoeuisymbol', 'simsunnsimsun', 'simsunextb', 'sitkasmallsitkatextsitkasubheadingsitkaheadingsitkadisplaysitkabanner', 'sitkasmallsitkatextboldsitkasubheadingboldsitkaheadingboldsitkadisplayboldsitkabannerbold', 'sitkasmallsitkatextbolditalicsitkasubheadingbolditalicsitkaheadingbolditalicsitkadisplaybolditalicsitkabannerbolditalic', 'sitkasmallsitkatextitalicsitkasubheadingitalicsitkaheadingitalicsitkadisplayitalicsitkabanneritalic', 'sylfaen', 'symbol', 'tahoma', 'timesnewroman', 'trebuchetms', 'verdana', 'webdings', 'wingdings', 'yugothicyugothicuisemiboldyugothicuibold', 'yugothicyugothicuilight', 'yugothicmediumyugothicuiregular', 'yugothicregularyugothicuisemilight', 'dengxian', 'fangsong', 'kaiti', 'simhei', 'holomdl2assets', 'extra', 'fzshuti', 'fzyaoti', 'lisu', 'stcaiyun', 'stfangsong', 'sthupo', 'stkaiti', 'stliti', 'stsong', 'stxihei', 'stxingkai', 'stxinwei', 'stzhongsong', 'youyuan', 'haettenschweiler', 'msoutlook', 'bookantiqua', 'centurygothic', 'bookshelfsymbol7', 'msreferencesansserif', 'msreferencespecialty', 'garamond', 'monotypecorsiva', 'bookmanoldstyle', 'algerian', 'baskervilleoldface', 'bauhaus93', 'bell', 'berlinsansfb', 'berlinsansfbdemi', 'bernardcondensed', 'bodonipostercompressed', 'britannic', 'broadway', 'brushscript', 'californianfb', 'centaur', 'chiller', 'colonna', 'cooperblack', 'footlight', 'freestylescript', 'harlowsolid', 'harrington', 'hightowertext', 'jokerman', 'juiceitc', 'kristenitc', 'kunstlerscript', 'lucidabright', 'lucidacalligraphy', 'lucidafaxregular', 'lucidafax', 'lucidahandwriting', 'magneto', 'maturascriptcapitals', 'mistral', 'modernno20', 'niagaraengraved', 'niagarasolid', 'oldenglishtext', 'onyx', 'parchment', 'playbill', 'poorrichard', 'ravie', 'informalroman', 'showcardgothic', 'snapitc', 'stencil', 'tempussansitc', 'vinerhanditc', 'vivaldi', 'vladimirscript', 'widelatin', 'century', 'wingdings2', 'wingdings3', 'arialms', 'msmincho', 'acaderef', 'aigdt', 'amdtsymbols', 'geniso', 'amgdt', 'bankgothic', 'bankgothicmedium', 'cityblueprint', 'commercialpi', 'commercialscript', 'countryblueprint', 'dutch801roman', 'dutch801', 'dutch801extra', 'euroroman', 'euroromanoblique', 'monospace821', 'panroman', 'romantic', 'romans', 'sansserif', 'sansserifboldoblique', 'sansserifoblique', 'stylus', 'superfrench', 'swiss721', 'swiss721outline', 'swiss721condensed', 'swiss721condensedoutline', 'swiss721blackcondensed', 'swiss721extended', 'swiss721blackextended', 'swiss721black', 'swiss721blackoutline', 'technicbold', 'techniclite', 'technic', 'universalmath1', 'vineta', 'isocpeur', 'isocteur', 'proxy9', 'proxy8', 'proxy7', 'proxy6', 'proxy5', 'proxy4', 'proxy3', 'symusic', 'symeteo', 'symath', 'symap', 'syastro', 'romant', 'romand', 'romanc', 'italict', 'greeks', 'greekc', 'gothicg', 'gothice', 'txt', 'simplex', 'scripts', 'scriptc', 'proxy2', 'proxy1', 'monotxt', 'italicc', '', 'isoct3', 'isoct2', 'isoct', 'isocp3', 'isocp2', 'isocp', 'gothici', 'gdt', 'complex', 'thcadsymbsttf', 'thcadsymbs', 'zwadobef', 'eurosign', 'lucidabrightregular', 'lucidasansregular', 'lucidasanstypewriter', 'lucidasanstypewriterregular', 'adobeheitistdregular', 'adobemingstdlight', 'adobemyungjostdmedium', 'adobepistd', 'adobesongstdlight', 'courierstd', 'courierstdbold', 'courierstdboldoblique', 'courierstdoblique', 'kozgopr6nmedium', 'kozminpr6nregular', 'myriadcad', 'hyswlongfangsong', 'swastro', 'olfsimplesansocregular', 'swcomp', 'swgothe', 'swgothg', 'swgothi', 'swgrekc', 'swgreks', 'swisop1', 'swisop2', 'swisop3', 'swisot1', 'swisot2', 'swisot3', 'swital', 'switalc', 'switalt', 'swmap', 'swmath', 'swmeteo', 'swmono', 'swmusic', 'swromnc', 'swromnd', 'swromns', 'swromnt', 'swscrpc', 'swscrps', 'swsimp', 'swtxt', 'swgdt', 'swlink', 'dejavusansmono', 'dejavusansmonooblique', 'freesans']
```

then you can pick one font like "arial"

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 25)
```